# Вопрос о правильности построения словосочетания

Tags: словосочетания

Мир взаимосвязан. Можно ли так писать? Или взаимосвязанными могут быть только элементы? Или здесь уместнее выражение "все взаимосвязано"?

Comment: @Вирази, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Вполне корректное словосочетание,используемое как философский тезис.

Мир есть взаимосвязанное единство, целостность.

..мир представляет собой материальное взаимосвязанное целое, развивающееся по законам природы

Мир-взаимосвязанное и развивающееся целое, где мир минералов вплотную подводит к растительному миру, а этот последний - к царству животных.

Если есть полная форма, то есть и краткая: мир взаимосвязан = все системы в мире взаимосвязаны.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%80+%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%80+%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%22&tbm=bks

Answer (score 1):

"Взаимосвязанными" могут быть названы не менее двух сущностей. Можно сказать: "всё в мире взаимосвязано", "мир вещей и мир идей взаимосвязаны" и т. п.

Comment: Уже наличие "взаимо-" в слове "взаимосвязан" подразумевает наличие более чем одного объекта или более чем одной сущности.

Comment: Поэтому и возникает противоречие между единственной названной сущностью (мир) и приписываемым ему свойстве множественных вещей.

Answer (score 0):

Вполне нормально, это метонимия.